# Pandas Cant Read Timestamp Column in csv File

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm working on a [quite big file](https://files.fm/u/wqajscrn) and with using the pd.read_csv command I get the following results:
[image]

I've already tried converter{1:str} and setting dtype without any luck.I used print (data.to_string()) and got the following:
[image] I cant reformat the file but when I tried using only a small portion of it everything worked fine.

Comment: Can you print the df using `print(df.to_string())`

Comment: @pissallI It took time but the problem remains the same. I'll edit the question including your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry but what is the problem?

Comment: @AntonvBR The second column includes timestamp values and read_csv command cant read them

Comment: Don't ask us to download a huge file when your problem can be reproduced by only the first 2-3 lines and 2-3 columns.  Just make the smallest example input and give it to us as plain text.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I might be wrong, but I've already pointed out the fact that using a smaller file doesnt reproduce the problem. That's why I am uploading the whole file